# Javascript Div Html contains many input

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a DIV in Html that contains several input The idea is to create the Div dynamically with a loop for if I click on the show button it takes a little time to display it is normal since we have 300 input in the DIV but my question is what is possible to display for example the first 10 input then the other 10 and etc ... so that do not wait a time to afichher at the same time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Div </h2>
<input id="ButtonShow" type="button" value="Show" onclick="show();"/>
<div id="p1"></div>

<script>

function show()
{
    for (i=0 ;i<350; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += 
               "<input type='checkbox' value='Callback' checked='checked'/><br>";
    }
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't modify the DOM on every iteration: https://jsfiddle.net/4rcw0s7e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery.

```
$("#p_id").append("<input type='checkbox' value='Callback' checked='checked'/><br>");
```

If there are still problems with slow, then you can use setTimeout:

```
function addCheckBox(offset)
{
    $("#p_id").append("<input type='checkbox' value='Callback' checked='checked'/><br>");
    if (offset < 290)
        window.setTimeout(()=> addCheckBox(offset + 10), 50);
}

addCheckBox(0);
```